# USB ports dissabled at Ubuntu kernal (works at Grub menu) 4 tries with 20.xx and 21.xx version. help please

Tags: usb, keyboard, bootloader

I have install Ubuntu on 3 computers, 2 were fine, one failed with Dummy Device for sound.
I tried all versions of repair found online - none worked.
So I reinstalled. Sound seem to be fixed during the process however.. it fails now at the USB recognition.
At boot I can use blue tooth keyboard to select the Grub choice but soon as Ubuntu loads, the USB ports are not seen.
I have seen a fix involving SSH to get a fix but .. and here it comes..
I cannot get and install ssh client without a functioning keyboard.
I am able to follow any instructions given however I am not in any way "literate" with Ubuntu or any Linux distro.
I can only assume there is a install command that will enable SSH at installation and boot up .. Or are there any other options I have not covered yet?
This troubled install is on a MeLE Intel PC Stick on which I performed all instructions on modifying the BIOS for Linux as needed, per MeLE instructions.
Thanks for any and all help!

Comment: how about a workaround for this...?By default, remote access is not allowed in Ubuntu 20.04 using the SSH, and we first have to enable the SSH. Just follow the step-by-step guide given below, and you will have the OpenSSH server installed and enabled on your ubuntu 20.04 LTS system for remote access.

Comment: OK -- time for update..

Comment: The 6th try is still another total failure. The 20.xx and 21.x versions both fail at the point of reboot.(just says reboot needed but no mention of remove Boot USB or leave it in - both methods fail the same way) Only to get to the sign on screen with no functioning USB ports, thus no keyboard and no way to sudo any repair! I tried Linux years ago and have always wanted to become a knowledgeable user learning all I can but in the end I will GLADLY pay what I need to Microsoft to get a STABLE OS I can rely on. This crap ain't prime time yet. Yes I'm P1ssed and uh .. thanks for the help!